# JDBC with Oracle - executeUpdate automatically changes status of AutoCommit

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc, autocommit

We have a Java application that uses connection pooling. Usuallay at the start of each function/process we use `setAutoCommit(false);` to switch off AutoCommit. And in the finally section, after commit/rollback we switch it back to ON using `setAutoCommit(true);`

From time to time we were getting this Exception in a few functions:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on
```

Upon investigation we found that **randomly** the AutoCommit status changes from OFF/false to ON/true after `executeUpdate` without any apparent reason.

```
status = connection.getAutoCommit(); // stores false
statement.executeUpdate(sQuery.toString());
status = connection.getAutoCommit(); // stores true
```

As I said it doesn't always happen. There is no other function call between these lines that could possibly change the status.

As a workaround we have restored the AutoCommit status after executeUpdate if it changes. But we need to know more as executeUpdate is used a few dozen time in the application.

Has anyone faced similar issue? Any solution other than the above?

We are using Java 1.8 with Oracle 11 and ojdbc8-19.3.0.0.jar

Answer (score 2):

A more plausible explanation is that the connection object is used by more than one thread concurrently, and the other thread has changed the auto-commit mode between your two getAutoCommit() calls. It is strongly recommended to not concurrently share a JDBC connection across threads for various reasons, one of which is the behavior you're seeing, but you could also end up dead-locking your database session.

The JDBC spec states that the calling commit() on a connection that has auto-commit mode enabled should throw an exception. But there is a JDBC property that can be used to relax this behavior: set "oracle.jdbc.autoCommitSpecCompliant" to "false". See the Javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jajdb/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#CONNECTION_PROPERTY_AUTO_COMMIT_SPEC_COMPLIANT).

Comment: but "relax this behavior" is more like hiding the error, not correcting it; assuming there are (valid) reasons/need for turning auto-commit off.

Comment: Yes relaxing the behavior is just to workaround a bogus application and is definitely not recommended.

Comment: We also suspect that some other usage instance in multi-user behavior is changing this property. Having said that, unless there is a bug in connection pooling and allocating mechanism, the connection is not being shared across threads.

Comment: Since you use connection pooling, perhaps there's a bug there. Perhaps you can change your prolog/epilog processing code to log which connection you set autocommit off / on to, to see if multiples of same connections are accessed somehow

Comment: How do you "release" the connection to the pool? And what kind of pool do you use